# Minimum of $f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_n}{x-b_n}$ occurs at extreme point?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Let $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ be real numbers and $b_1,\ldots,b_n>1$. Define $$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{a_i}{x-b_i}.$$ Is it always true that $f(x)\geq\min\{f(0),f(1)\}$ for all $x\in[0,1]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not always true.  As a counterexample, let $n=2$, $a_1=-\frac14$, $a_2=4$, $b_1=2.5$ and $b_2=8$.  Then, we have

$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{4x-10}+\frac{4}{x-8}$$

which attains its minimum at $x=\frac23$.

Answer (score 0):

Since The derivative of a term $a/(x-b)$ is $-a/(x-b)^2,$ you could  also impose the restriction that all the $a_i$ are positive, or all are negative. Then $f(x)$ will be decreasing or increasing and you get your conclusion.

Comment: Initially, that is what I thought the intent might be.  But upon reflecting, the $a$'s were stated only to be real, while the $b$'s were given a definite sign inasmuch as all are greater than unity.